# Where do users go to ask a question about their EOL version of Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, scope

Although this subject was discussed in 2012, 2016, etc., I did't see any current discussions of it, so please forgive me as I rattle the cage again:

On AskUbuntu, I frequently see questions marked as, "off topic," because they are for versions of Ubuntu that have passed their end-of-life.

Many of us, for whatever reason, are stuck on hardware that cannot be upgraded to the newer releases of Ubuntu.  In my case, for example, my video card is no longer supported by the kernel beyond 14.04.

Where can **these** users go to ask for help?
Should there be a distinct community for "askUbuntu-EOL" or something similar?  And, if we did have such a community on StackExchange, would any of the gurus upon whom we all depend be interested enough to participate on it?

Comment: Thanks, @Kulfy. (and @terdon) for the links and suggestions.  I think [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com) are good suggestions.  I also added [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) as a possible place for these folks to ask for help with their older releases of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best place for them to ask their questions would be on the retrocomputing community.
[Retrocomputing Beta](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/)

...Or on Unix & Linux or Super User, as suggested by @terdon.
[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
[Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure if [retrocomputing.se] accepts those questions since they don't even have `ubuntu` tag.

Comment: @Kulfy Good point.  I go there for my Atari questions but I didn't think of looking for tags. Every day, I learn more about StackExchange.  This is a wonderful web site!  I am in awe of how well designed it is and how everyone works together on it.